# Exclude nested documents based on a condition

Tags: mongodb, projection

I have a document in the following form

```
{
  "_id": "5c9a53b348a0ac000140b5f9",
  "e": [
    {
      "_id": "d6c74cd5-5808-4b0c-b857-57ddbcc72ce5",
      "isDeleted": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "d6c74cd5-5808-4b0c-b857-57ddbcc72ce6",
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Every document has a list of elements on it, each of the elements which may or may not be deleted. By default, I don't want to return the deleted data. Right now, I filter them server-side but that still means a lot of data gets transmitted unnecessarily. Is it possible to exclude this data on the database?

I've looked at `$elemMatch` but that only returns a single value so it doesn't look like the right tool for the job.

Is there a way to project a document with an array of nested documents to only include those subdocuments that adhere to a certain condition?

Comment: What output do you expect from the above sample document?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Every field from the document but the `e` collection should only contain elements that have `isDeleted == false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "e": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$e"
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.isDeleted", true] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Awesome! It took me a while to get this expressed in C# (which was a bit more complicated because my actual scenario is a property `DateTime? DeletedAt` rather than an easy `bool`) but I seem to have it working in the end. Just to make sure we're on the same page: essentially we are overwriting the `e` collection with the result of a filter, is that correct? Do you know if that is a red flag performance wise or is it indeed the optimization I hope for?

Comment: This approach uses aggregation -- can this also be used when you do an update first? i.e. I have two paths: one to get the data and one to update the data. The update path will return the modified document after the update. I can apply the aggregation to the pure "read" path but the "update" one seems to be mixing two incompatible approaches.

Comment: ***e collection with the result of a filter, is that correct?*** yes. Well there is no effect of the `$addFields` or `$project` on performance both will give you the same result with the same efficiency. ***can this also be used when you do an update first?*** I think you cannot. Both the update and aggregation are different functions/queries and work differently.

Comment: That's fair enough. Can you think of an alternative approach that works for update commands?

Comment: Well I always call multiple api's for such type of operations instead of doing in the same. And as mongodb is scalable database it is always easy to perform such type of operations.